# ?: in javascript objec property

Tags: google-maps, typescript

I have a question about some javascript code I saw in the google maps javascript library.

## 1.

```
constructor (sw?: LatLng, ne?: LatLng);
```

the above is inside a class called latlng. Im not sure what is happening here. Why is the '?:' used, and what does it mean for the parameters being passed into the function.

## 2.

```
lat(): number;
```

The above is inside another object. I'm thinking this tells me that this object's function returns a number, but I'm not sure this is the case since I thought you couldn't specify return types in javascript.

## 3.

```
export interface MapOptions {
        backgroundColor?: string;
        center?: LatLng;
        disableDefaultUI?: boolean;
        disableDoubleClickZoom?: boolean;
        draggable?: boolean;
        draggableCursor?: string;
        draggingCursor?: string;
        heading?: number;
        ...etc.
        }
```

What the heck is all this? Is this even legal javascript. What does the '?:' operator (or whatever you wanna call it) is doing here?

I'm an experienced c++ and type definition is what my mind sees every where. I'm trying to adjust to javascript variables with not types but this here is just a little confusing... is everything to the right of the colon just assigning types to the properties on the left? or is the comparison operator being used here to compare something?

UPDATE:
I guess this is not javascript after all. Dont understand why down voted for it being typescript. So much of this being a learning environment ha!

Comment: That's not JavaScript.

Comment: It seems to be a part of the documentation, the `?` marks the function-arguments/object-properties as optional

Comment: The `lat():number` probably is a method `lat()` of some object which returns a value of type `number`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code is `TypeScript`, not JavaScript.

`?` denotes that the paremeter (or interface members) are optional.

`:number` denotes that the return type is a `number`.

More on basic type annotations : http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-system.html